# probability and diffrentiation plot

Tags: matlab, probability, differentiation

we were given a class activity to do following: Plot pf (f) and df/dg which are supposed to be inverse of each other. Verify that pg(g) = pf (f) df/dg is more uniform. Please can someone explain to me what it means? I have to plot it in matlab which I just started using.

Comment: Need more information about what the variables/equations are in your question (e.g. pf(f), df/dg). Do you have expressions for these equations? What do they represent?

In general, I can point you towards the symbolic math toolbox for rearranging equations (if that's necessary) and the 'plot' function for plotting functions.

Comment: Only this statement was given regarding this question. But in context to the other questions I think pf(f) is probability of frequency for each pixel in image, and df/dg would be diffrentiation but not sure about it

Comment: I can tell from your question that, your problem is related to how to find the pdf of a function of a random variable. your random variable is f and g is a function of f for example g=f^2. So your question as you stated yet has nothing to do with Matlab and I don't think you will get help here. I suggest that you ask your question on https://dsp.stackexchange.com. Good luck

Comment: No I have an image I took prob. of frequencies of pixels. Now I have to find out what df/dg is. and then I have to plot them.

Comment: And it is to be done on matlab. Its a task in digital image processing